# How to loop through a list of dataframes while applying different functions?

Tags: r

I have a list of several dataframes. I wish loop through each dataframe and change the first column to Date, change rownames, etc. Then I want to return each dataframe to the global environment. Here is my current, nonworking code.

```
meta = lapply(meta, function(x){
x[[1]] = as.Date(x)
rownames(x) = x[[1]]
x$Date = NULL
return(x)
})
```

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Comment: Does `meta = lapply(meta, function(x){ x[[1]] = as.Date(x[[1]]); rownames(x) = x[[1]]; x[[1]] = NULL; return(x) })` do what you're hoping?

Comment: *Then I want to return each dataframe to the global environment* ... why not keep them in a list instead of flooding global env with many likely similar structured objects? You lose no functionality of data frame if it is in list.

Comment: @duckmayr This works great, except it does not return each dataframe to the global environment. Also, I have a follow up question. All of my dataframes have a .csv ending, so for example "GOOG.csv". Is there any way to remove the ".csv" ending and retain the ticker?

Comment: @duckmayr I'm having an issue with the rownames(x) = x[[1]] assignment. I get the error "attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions". Any idea how to get around this? Everything else works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @thefishy75 That indicates there are elements of your list `meta` that are not in fact dataframes; couldn't be more help without more information on your data.

Comment: @duckmayr Thats strange, I used str() to look at each entry in the list, and each is of type "dataframe". It is interesting to note, that your loop works on about half of the dataframes before failing and stopping. I wonder what it could be about the first failed dataframe that causes a failure?

Comment: @duckymayr also to note, if I do the looping manually, each dataframe is properly converted.

Comment: @thefishy75 Try changing `rownames(x) = x[[1]]` to `if (length(dim(x)) > 0) rownames(x) = x[[1]] else print(name)`. Then if one of the elements would trigger that error, it should instead print out the name of the problematic dataframe, which might help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want

```
invisible(lapply(names(meta), function(name) {
    x <- meta[[name]]
    x[[1]] = as.Date(x[[1]])
    rownames(x) = x[[1]]
    x[[1]] = NULL
    assign(sub(".csv", "", name), x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}))
```

See `help("assign")`.

Comment: Thank you for the help!